# I installed League of Legends and I can't open it in Wine

Tags: wine, games

I Installed [League Of Legends](http://na.leagueoflegends.com/) in Wine, but when I click on the shortcut nothing happens.

Answer (score 0):

Every Application that can be used in Wine usually has an entry in the [WineHQ AppDB](https://appdb.winehq.org/).  In your case, the main AppPage is [WineHQ - League of Legends](https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=19141).  You always want to see if there are any Installation instructions available.  As you can see there are instructions for this entry.